# Axis wsdl2java not generating all interfaces in stub

Tags: axis, binding, stub, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate stub using wsdl2java.bat, my wsdl consists of two bindings. I see that wsdl2bat creates interface for operations in the first binding but does not generate anything for operations in the seconds binding. wsdl2java.bat -uri http://... -o client -d adb -s -u.

For example the code should look like this

```
try {
     //Create the stub by passing the AXIS_HOME and target EPR.
     //We pass null to the AXIS_HOME and hence the stub will use the current directory as the AXIS_HOME 
     Axis2SampleDocLitPortTypeStub stub= new Axis2SampleDocLitPortTypeStub(null,
                                "http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Axis2SampleStub");
     //Create the request document to be sent.
     EchoString  reqDoc= EchoString.Factory.newInstance();
     reqDoc.setEchoString("Echo this");
     //invokes the Web service.
     EchoStringReturn resDoc=stub.echoString(reqDoc);
     System.out.println(resDoc.getEchoStringReturn());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem here is, I do see a the method getEchoStringReturn in resDoc instance of stub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy one is::

E:\use\jars\axis jars>set classpath=%classpath%;axis-1.4.jar;axis-ant.jar;axis-1.4.jar;commons-discovery-0.5.jar;commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar;jaxrpc-api.jar;log4j-1.2.jar;org.apache.commons.logging.jar;saaj.jar;wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;

and then::

E:\use\jars\axis jars>java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -N"urn:/crmondemand/xml/Contact/Data"="crmondemand.xml.Contact.Data" -N"urn:/crmondemand/xml/Contact/Query"="crmondemand.xml.Contact.Query" -N"urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/contact/10/2004"="crmondemand.ws.ecbs.contact"  -o E:\use\test2 "Contact1.wsdl"